# Override package with local package [Overleaf]

Tags: texlive, expl3, xparse, overleaf, texlive-2017

For a rather large project I unfortunately need to use Overleaf. The problem with this is that it uses TexLive 2017.

My question is:

- **Is there an easy way to use packages from the newest TexLive distribution in Overleaf?**

Said in a different way, is there an easy way to add a local package X and make other packages refer to it, instead of the one provided by the current TexLive version?

In particular my problem is that I need a newer version of `xparse`.
For a small document I was able to get around this by

- Downloading [`l3packages`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages) and [`l3kernel`](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel?lang=en) into their separate folders.
- Running `tex` on the relevant `*.ins` files
- Changing every instance of `RequirePackage{xparse}` to `RequirePackage{l3packages/xparse}` and similarly for `xfp` and the other packages. I also had to link to the updated version of `l3kernel` to make it work.

However, for my main document I am also using [`fontspec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec?lang=en). This provided a major hurdle, as it seems this package uses `xparse` *everywhere*.
I tried to search through the entire directory and changing every instance of `xparse` to the local one. However, Overleaf still complained about conflicts between different version of `xparse`. At this point, I gave up and turned to *tex.exchange* for some much needed guidance.

Any help in making a local newly updated (2019) version of `xparse` work with Overleaf (TexLive 2017) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) If you put the package files in the root directory of your project, it's not necessary to change the paths for `\RequirePackage`. But this is not always practical for large packages with many dependencies. Sorry for the delay in updating our TeX Live images. We're testing TeX Live 2018 right now. If you have a project that would benefit from the update, please contact us at support@overleaf.com with the project's URL and we'll update it for you as soon as the update is ready.

Comment: Without starting a long discussion, why not upgrade straight to TexLive2019?

Comment: Because we prepare our compiler images using versions later in the yearly cycle, to a) catch a greater percentage of the package updates for a particular TeX Live release and b) reduce the incidence of any package conflicts that are sometimes caused if a core package is updated and authors of dependent packages haven't released updates yet. TeX Live 2019 will be coming after we have shipped TeX Live 2018, with (I'm hoping) much less of a delay as we resume a more regular update cycle after the merger of Overleaf and ShareLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really *not* change the package files. Human error will always come back to haunt you :-)

Searching a bit I found [this Overleaf help page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I%20have%20a%20lot%20of%20.cls,%20.sty,%20.bst%20files,%20and%20I%20want%20to%20put%20them%20in%20a%20folder%20to%20keep%20my%20project%20uncluttered.%20But%20my%20project%20is%20not%20finding%20them%20to%20compile%20correctly), which helps to solve half the problem. Create an empty file called `.latexmkrc` in your project folder, and then add the following line to it:

```sh
$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./l3stuff//:' . $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};
```

Now create an empty folder called `l3stuff` (or whatever name you used in the line above).

Now, to have `fontspec` working you go to CTAN and download the TDS archive for the [`l3kernel`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel.tds.zip), [`l3packages`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages.tds.zip), [`l3backend`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3backend.tds.zip), and of course, [`fontspec`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec.tds.zip). Extract all of these. The extracted archive will have three folders: `doc`, `source`, and `tex`. You want `tex/latex/<package>`. Now upload *everything* into that `l3stuff` folder you created before. All files must be directly inside `l3stuff`, and not in subfolders. If you did everything correctly, you should now have an up-to-date version of `fontspec` in Overleaf.

Comment: Thanks! I totally agree that one should not change the package files and that is partly the reason I asked this question. Should I upload everything `doc`, `source` and `tex`? Or just the part in `tex/latex/<package>`?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Only the files in the `tex` tree are needed. The `source` and `doc` directories contain the sources and documentation related stuff (unsurprisingly). You don't need these to run the code.

Comment: Olenik Right. I am guessing there is a better place than Tex.exchange to discuss this. I followed every step and it works fine in my test document. However, in my main document my main files are located in subdirectories, with the sty files in another one. I tried to write './_sty/l3stuff//:' alas this does not work. Is the problem that my main files are in subdirectories, or that I have incorrectly named the path to l3stuff?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar After a few tests I found out that the `.latexmkrc` file must be in the root directory of your project, even if the main `.tex` is in a sub folder. However, the path you give to `l3stuff` in `.latexmkrc` should be relative to the main `.tex`, and _not_ to `.latexmkrc`. Knowing that, and if I understood correctly how your directories are organised, I think `'../_sty/l3stuff//:'` (note the two dots, instead of one) should work for you.