# How to compile a document which uses a modern TL2019 package (relying on new l3kernel and l3packages) under an older kernel (TL 2017)?

Tags: amsmath, texlive, expl3, xparse, diffcoeff

I am in a tricky situation as explained below.

I have just finished writing a (rather long) math-heavy article which makes use of the package [`diffcoeff`](https://ctan.org/pkg/diffcoeff) for easy writing of (partial & ordinary) differentials. This is intended for submission to an IEEE journal and is to be processed with `pdflatex`.

However, I just discovered that IEEE's article submission system (ScholarOne portal) is unable to process my tex file, since it apparently uses an older version of TexLive (TL2017)

The error is owing to my use of the `diffcoeff` package which relies on the facilities provided by the `l3kernel`,`expl3` and other latex3-related modern infrastructure.

How can I fix this issue with the **least possible effort** and make the document compile under TL2017? Rewriting pages of equations using another package shall of course be only a last option.

Copying the latest `diffcoeff.sty` to the project's root moves the error to `xparse`. Copying the latest `xparse.sty` leads to an error complaining *"too old kernel"*. Copying the latest `expl3.sty` leads to an error which says *"mismatched expl3"* and so on.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\diffdef { p }
{
  op-symbol = \partial ,
  left-delim = \left .,
  right-delim = \right | ,
  subscr-nudge = 0 mu
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
   \diff*{\mean{q}_\lambda}{t} = -30 \frac{D_{\text{s}_\lambda}} R^2_{\text{p}_\lambda}} - \frac{45}{2}\frac{j_\lambda}{R^2_{\text{p}_\lambda}}
\end{equation}
```

which gives the following error when compiled under IEEE

```
?Undefined control sequence.
l.12164     \diffdef
                     { p }
```

Here are some relevant lines from the log

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2017/05/29 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count389
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count390
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count391
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count392
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count393
)
Package: diffcoeff 2016/06/27 v1.0 Write differential coefficients easily.
\l__diffco_curr_tok_int=\count394
\l__diffco_curr_state_int=\count395
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \diffset with sig. 'o' on line 108.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \diff with sig. 'somt/mg' on line 190.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \Diff with sig. 'ommg' on line 200.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \diffd with sig. 'ommg' on line 210.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \Diffd with sig. 'ommg' on line 220.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \diffp with sig. 'soomt/mg' on line 351.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \jacob with sig. 'mm' on line 356.
.................................................
)
/compile/main.tex:12164: Undefined control sequence.
l.12164     \diffdef
                     { p }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


/compile/main.tex:12164: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12164     \diffdef { p
                         }
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

/compile/main.tex:12166: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.12166         op-symbol = \partial
                                     ,
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

Comment: The LaTeX3 kernel changed a _lot_ since 2012, so just adding the missing definitions will probably get you copying most of `expl3` into your article. In your place, I think I'd drop the package and write the differentials by hand or try to write the missing commands myself, in a simpler way. You can also try to copy the entire `l3kernel` (and `l3packages` and `l3backend` into your submission, but even that might not work due to engine requirements (I'm not sure how far back current `expl3` can go).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik that's way too much manual work to edit the 45 or so differential equations in my article. Is there any other package that closely resembles the macros of `diffcoeff`?

Comment: The website doesn't explicitly say that they are (still) using texlive 2012. Did you actually tried and failed? Did you see a log?

Comment: @Krishna That I don't know, sorry.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ha. I jumped the gun a bit. I inspected the log files and looks like they are using TL 2017 (in collaboration with Overleaf). I shall update the question accordingly.  However, the problem persists.

Comment: The error message suggests that the diffcoeff package is older. The documentation says \diffdef has replaced \diffset. So you could either try to adjust to the older syntax, or try to add the new version of diffcoeff to your folder.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer   copying the latest `diffcoeff.sty` to the project's root moves the error to xparse. Copying the latest `xparse.sty` leads to an error complaining _"too old kernel"_. Copying the latest `expl3.sty` leads to an error which says _"mismatched expl3"_ and so on.

Comment: Well then use the other option: get hold of an older documentation of diffcoeff (e.g. through overleaf) and adjust the syntax. (but expl3 is not only the style, you need also the expl3-code file and other stuff from l3kernel and l3backend. )

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I shall change to the older syntax if that's the best course of action. However, just for my curiosity, if I just copy over all the `sty` files from `l3kernel` and `l3backend`, in addition to `xparse.sty` and `diffcoeff.sty`, is this expected to work?

Comment: No idea. If the engine supports all the primitives it could work. But the only way to find out is to try (which I never did).

Comment: @Krishna I should note that Overleaf uses TL 2018 already, and with that your example document compiles fine (after I add `\let\mean\bar` and a missing `{` before `R^2` and the missing `\end{document}`. But yes, the current LaTeX3 kernel should work in Overleaf, given you download all the necessary files: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505303/134574

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I did the steps given in the solution in your linked answer. This helped to make some progress. However, now the error says `LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type"
! 
! Unknown argument type '!' for the command '\diff'.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  
                                                  
l.338   }
          % end of \diff`  . From the log files, it infer that they are running TL2017.

Comment: @Krishna The error message is from an old `xparse`, and the formatting of the message indicates an old `expl3`. It looks like Overleaf didn't pick up your uploaded files, for some reason.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I see. Thank you. I have a flat `l3stuff` folder with the following files downloaded latest from CTAN: `expl3-code.tex expl3-generic.tex expl3.ltx expl3.lua expl3.sty l3backend-dvipdfmx.def l3backend-dvips.def l3backend-dvisvgm.def l3backend-pdfmode.def l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def l3debug.def l3deprecation.def l3doc.cls l3docstrip.tex l3keys2e.sty l3str-enc-iso88591.def l3str-enc-iso885910.def l3str-enc-iso885911.def l3str-enc-iso885913.def l3str-enc-iso885914.def l3str-enc-iso885915.def l3str-enc-iso885916.def l3str-enc-iso88592.def l3str-enc-iso88593.def l3str-enc-iso88594.def`

Comment: `l3str-enc-iso88595.def l3str-enc-iso88596.def l3str-enc-iso88597.def l3str-enc-iso88598.def l3str-enc-iso88599.def xfp.sty xfrac.sty xparse.sty xtemplate.sty`

Comment: @Krishna Can you show me the log, please?

Comment: simpler than updating their system would be to get your document to run in tl2017 (eg try it on overleaf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are best to get the pre-extracted zip files from CTAN:

- [`l3backend`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3backend.tds.zip)
- [`l3kernel`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel.tds.zip)
- [`l3packages`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages.tds.zip)

Extract all three and copy *everything* from the `tex/latex/l3...` directories into wherever you are expected to upload 'support' packages from. (In the case of `l3packages`, you can just upload the content of `tex/latex/l3packages/xparse`.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an up-to-date MiKTeX. The equation you provide is missing a left brace before `R^2`. When I insert that, and change `\mean` to, say, `\overline`, it compiles for me. Reducing the content of the entire equation simply to `\mean{q}` and then trying to compile gives an 'undefined control sequence' message (this is with or without `diffcoeff`).

However, `diffcoeff` does require a reasonably up-to-date `l3kernel`. It uses a candidate function `\seq_mapthread_function:NNN` which is not part of the kernel proper as yet, although it has 'been around' for some time.